# Authorization issue in Listen 360 API

Tags: c#, rest

We are facing an issue while pulling out data from Listen 360 API. We are using following Code:

```
class Program
{
    private const string URL =      "https://9833bf430be5620b7fa941ee5c3c7e2add61a86e:X@app.listen360.com/organizations/594214508264690689/reviews.xml";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);         

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body. Blocking!              
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

When the URL is directly hit on browser the XML response is recieved. But when we are trying to access it programatically we get "Unauthorized 401" response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve using api key as a username and replacing X with password for the listen 360 account.

```
class Program
{
 private const string URL =      "https://9833bf430be5620b7fa941ee5c3c7e2add61a86e:password@app.listen360.com/organizations/594214508264690689/reviews.xml";


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);         

    // List data response.
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;  // Blocking call!
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Parse the response body. Blocking!              
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

}